# A word to describe a crafty person who always manages to get his own way or turn things to his own advantage

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

The word I'm looking for is a noun. It should be a single word, and fit here: "Jimmy is really a ............  Even after all his shenanigans were made public, he still got the committee to support him."

Comment: Snake, or perhaps 'true politician'? Also, people whose bad deeds 'can't stick' are termed slippery. 'Slippery as an eel'

Comment: a _player_ ?...

Comment: conniver, charmer, swindler, fox, rogue, gull, Machiavelli, genius, schemer, manipulator, contriver...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**svengali**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/svengali): "One who manipulates or controls another as by some mesmeric or sinister influence; especially a coach, mentor or industry mogul."

"[**Teflon**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teflon_%28nickname%29) is a nickname given to persons, particularly in politics, to whom criticism does not seem to stick."

> Ronald Reagan, the President of the United States, was called by his detractors "the Teflon president."

--[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teflon_%28nickname%29)

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to consider **syndicator**:

```
syndicate (verb, transitive): to subject to or manage as a syndicate
```

by which a syndicate is:

```
 (noun) an association of persons officially authorized to undertake a duty or negotiate business
```

*from m-w.com*